# Convert String to DTO in the validator of constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate, dto

I have this field in a DTO:

```
  private List<RoleDTO> roles;
```

It has a validator:

```
      public class InternalUserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<InternalUserConstraint, Object> {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
            private String[] rolesAsString;
            private List<RoleDTO> roles;

        .
        .
        .

            @Override
            public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        //here i get as string, for example: RoleDTO{id=1, name='ADMIN'}
         rolesAsString = BeanUtils.getArrayProperty(value, rolesFieldName);//should i use also getproperty again?

        //then i try to convert to arraylist:
        roles = (List<RoleDTO>) mapper.convertValue(rolesAsString, RoleDTO.class);
```

but it gives

> Cannot construct instance of `model.RoleDTO` (out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

So, while in debug, i also tried this:

```
(List<RoleDTO>) mapper.convertValue("{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"sad\"}", RoleDTO.class)
```

This time:

> Cannot construct instance of `model.RoleDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"id":5,"name":"sad"}')
>    at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

What can i do?

This is **RoleDTO**:

```
 public class RoleDTO implements Serializable {

        private Long id;

        private String name;
//getters setters
    public RoleDTO() {
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add an explicit constructor with your id and name then?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot construct instance of model.RoleDTO (out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

This Error Means you are trying to deserialize JSONArray to the RoleDto object.. Which is not possible.

The `rolesAsString` here has value of something like `"[{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"sad\"}]"`

Use `ObjectMapper` with `TypeReference` like this..

```
mapper.readValue(rolesAsString, new TypeReference<List<RoleDTO>>() {
    });
```